# How can I Translate store page

Tags: magento2, store-view

I have two store : one is Default English and one is France.here is my csv file for France.I don't know this is right way or not . But know any changes happening after store switching

```
"Add to Wish List", "Liste de souhaits"
"Add to Compare","Comparer"
"Your Checkout Progress","Commander"
"Card Verification Number","CVV"
"Items %1-%2 of %3", "% 3 articles"
"Regular Price","était"
"Shop By","Filtre"
"Remove item","Retirer"
"Proceed to Checkout",  "Aller à la caisse"
"Grand Total", "Total estimé"
"Review by", "par"
"View Order", "Vue"
"Update Shopping Cart","Mise à jour panier"
"Print Order", "Impression"
"Move to Wish List","Déplacer"
"Copie dans la liste de souhaits","Copie"
"Move Selected to Wish List", "Déplacer sélectionné"
"Copy Selected to Wish List","Copier sélectionné"
"%1 items in wish list", "%1 items"
"1 item in wish list", "1 item"
"Continue to Shipping Information", "Select Shipping Method".
```

One question more I do not have any Idea how to change Email , login , create account and other default message in France.

Here is my default English **CSV** file

```
"Add to Wish List", "Wish List"
"Add to Compare", "Compare"
"Your Checkout Progress", "Checkout Progress"
"Card Verification Number", "CVV"
"Items %1-%2 of %3","%3 items"
"Regular Price", "was"
"Shop By","Filter"
"Remove item", "Remove"
"Proceed to Checkout", "Go to Checkout"
"Grand Total", "Estimated Total"
"Review by", "By"
"View Order", "View"
"Update Shopping Cart", "Update Cart"
"Print Order", "Print"
"Move to Wish List","Move"
"Copy to Wish List","Copy"
"Move Selected to Wish List", "Move Selected"
"Copy Selected to Wish List", "Copy Selected"
"%1 items in wish list", "%1 items"
"1 item in wish list", "1 item"
"Continue to Shipping Information", "Select Shipping Method"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All magento default messages will change automatically by setting store language for your french store

You can set store language from **Admin->Store->Configuration**

Select Store from Store view in upper section

Go to **General->Locale Options** select french language

[image]

Add file to your theme at

**app/design/frontend/Vendorname/Your-Theme-Name/i18n/fr_FR.csv**

Comment: Each and every thing is added,  but nothing happen

Comment: Let me know if you know other way to convert this

Comment: no sorry i don't know

Comment: what do you mean by question important?